# NHibernate combination and using OR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I have 3 variables in my filter:
`int? Owner`, `int? Watcher`, `int? CreatedBy`.

Now, depending of what is entered in filter (`if CreatedBy.HasValue` etc), i want to combine my query in NHibernate with OR statements. So far I have

```
if (filter.Owner.HasValue)
{
    criteria.Add(Expression.Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.User.Id", filter.Owner.Value))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.Status", 0)));
}

if (filter.Watcher.HasValue)
{
    criteria.Add(Expression.Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.User.Id", filter.Watcher.Value))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.Status", 1)));
}

if (filter.CreatedBy.HasValue)
{
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", filter.CreatedBy));
}
```

before, I added createAlias etc... But, how to combine those 3 queryies in one query with OR according to variables entered in filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, that the first part *(you already have)* is ok and also the second would be very straightforward. The way how to process that could be:

```
// this would be the collector of criteria
var restrictions = new List<ICriterion>();

if (filter.Owner.HasValue)
{
    restrcitons.Add(Expression.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.User.Id", filter.Owner.Value))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.Status", 0))
    );
}

if (filter.Watcher.HasValue)
{
    restricitons.Add(Expression.Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.User.Id", filter.Watcher.Value))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ou.Status", 1))
    );
}

if (filter.CreatedBy.HasValue)
{
    restrictions.Add(Restrictions.Eq("u.Id", filter.CreatedBy));
}

// now we can inject the result of the above code into 
// Disjunction or Conjunction...
if(restrictions.Count > 0)
{
    var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
    restrictions .ForEach(r => disjunction.Add(r));
    criteria.Add(disjunction)
}
```

Also, I would `CreateAlias` somewhere inside of the `if` - close to decision if the JOIN will be required or not (based on search parameters). Unless you are checking that elsewhere.

And maybe try to move the `if` into methods. They can take `restrictions` and `criteria` and decide how to handle them. it would be like this

```
RestrictOwner  (filter, restrictions, criteria);
RestrictWatcher(filter, restrictions, criteria);
RestrictCreator(filter, restrictions, criteria);

if(restrictions.Count ...
```

And later, they could be maybe even more generic...